# Exporting column vector as matrix in latex via "Copy as" doesn't always work. Example with vector

Tags: matrix, export

I want **the simplest way** of exporting matrices, and vector from mathematica to Latex.

Usually, I display my matrices in MatrixForm and copy as Latex to paste in my latex document. However it seems it doesn't always work, take the following code:

```
vv = {1, 2};
vv // MatrixForm
```

If from the display you do "copy as -> Latex", it returns you:

```
\{1,2\}
```

Instead of (for example):

```
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}
```

Which would match the mathematica display. If I input a matrix however (thus having more than 1 column), it works as it should.

How to make it really returns me something that will look like a column vector in latex ?

Comment: In version 12, I only get `array`, not `pmatrix`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I don't necesserally want a pmatrix and indeed it is not what it returns me for a "real" matrix (not a column vector). But I want a proper array to represent the column vector which he doesn't give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
export[v_?VectorQ] := export@Partition[vv, 1];
export[A_?MatrixQ] := CopyToClipboard@TeXForm@A;
```

and then

```
vv // export
```

?

A way to enforce `pmatrix` could be

```
export[v_?VectorQ] := export@Partition[vv, 1];
export[A_?MatrixQ] := CopyToClipboard@StringJoin[
    "\\begin{pmatrix}\n",
    ExportString[
     Join[
      Map[TeXForm, A, {2}],
      Append[ConstantArray["\\\\", {Length[A] - 1, 1}], {""}],
      2],
     "Table",
     "FieldSeparators" -> " & "
     ],
    "\n\\end{pmatrix}"
    ];
```

Btw., `MatrixForm` is super superfluous here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So actually the "real" answer inside is that I have to do Partition[vv, 1] to tell mathematica to write it as a matrix (even if it is a column vector). So that when I export in latex he knows he has to write a column vector using array. Would you confirm ?

Comment: _Mathematica_ just does not distinguish between "column vectors" and "row vectors". But you can transform an $n$-vector  `v` into a $n \times 1$-matrix with `Partition[v,1]`. Btw., I strongly believe that _Mathematica_ is a "she". But who knows...?

Comment: Ok thanks. Well actually I'm french so I sometime replace it by he or she as we don't have impersonal pronouns ^^